# C++ parse strings with while / do while loops

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am trying to parse the results of `lsblsk` with a solution inspired by other threads here in StackOverflow. I am definitely missing something about while and do-while loops. Can anybody please tell me why the first line is not being parsed in this code? Thank you very much in advance for your help.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string Get(const std::string& s, const unsigned int _n)
{
    std::istringstream is(s);
    std::string field, line;
    int n = _n;
    while (std::getline(is, line))
    {
        do
        {
            if (!(is >> line))
            {
                std::cout << " finished " << "\n";
                return "";
            }
        }
        while (n-- != 0);
        line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\"'), line.end());
        line = line.substr(line.find_first_of('=') + 1);

        if (line.empty())
        {
            line = "empty\n";
            std::cout << line;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << line << "\n";
        }
        n = _n;
    }
    return line;
}

std::string exec(const char* cmd)
{
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string token;
    std::string nth;
    std::string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr)
    {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string res;
    res = exec("lsblk -atpiP -o NAME,RM,SIZE,RO,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID");
    std::cout << res << "\n\n\n";
    std::cout << Get(res, 5) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::getline(is, line)` reads the first line, `(is >> line)` drops off the first lines, reads the next string value.

Comment: So, how can I substitute that check so that the line will not be skipped?

Comment: Are you sure you need the first line? lsblk outputs the table header in the first line.

Comment: with the -P option yes, I do need the first line

Comment: Remove P, the parsing will be much easier.

Comment: Without P lsblk produces empty fields which in turn create other problems. Any other solution?

Comment: Use `lsblk -atpi -o MOUNTPOINT` and remove ` const unsigned int _n`.

Comment: Fine, that works. Thanks.
Just for my curiosity: is it possible to change the implementation to mantain that while(getline... ? Kind of 

while(getline(is,line))
set_the_cursor_at_the_beginning_of_this_line()

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you want to much for QA site.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the last comment. There are thousend of posts where codes have been completely rewritten, comment by comment. What's the problem with mine?